# Cannot find "." symbol in Array List

Tags: java, arraylist

Cannot find "." symbol in Array List

```
public class ArrayTools
{
    //instance variables and constructors could be present, but are not necessary

//sumSection will return the sum of the numbers
//from start to stop, not including stop

public static int sumSection(int[] numArray, int start, int stop)
{
    int sum=0;

    for ( int i = start; i < stop; i++)
    {
            sum += numArray.get(i);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: `numArray` is an array, try `numArray[i]` instead of `numArray.get(i)`.

Comment: Including code is good. Including a question is even better.

Answer (score 4):

get is a method of list, not array.

Use: `numArray[i]`

Answer (score 3):

Using like this is for the `List`:

```
  sum += numArray.get(i);
```

But in your case use this for the `array`:

```
  sum += numArray[i];
```

Answer (score 2):

`get()` is a method of `List`.

This is first what you should try to change to fix the `"."` error. Then you have another problem. Convert array to the list is redundant, so you can move it out of the loop.

If you pre-initialize the list before using in the loop. You have to use `Integer[]` instead of `int[]` in the method signature because `Arrays.asList()` incorrect converting array to the `List`.

```
public static int sumSection(Integer[] numArray, int start, int stop)
  {
    int sum=0;

    List<Integer> numList =  Arrays.asList(numArray);

    for ( int i = start; i < stop; i++)
    {
      sum += numList.get(i);
    }
    return sum;
  }
```

You have tried to use `get()` method out of the array, but arrays are objects that don't implement a `List` interface.

You misunderstood  that `numArray.get(i)` is wrong and `numArray` is not a `List`. If you want to use List and its `get()` method you should convert it to the `List` before you use `get()` of this object.

Comment: Why create a redundant ArrayList? Why not just numArray[i]?

Comment: Your code will either not compile or cause an exception during runtime. The result of `Arrays.asList(numArray)` is _NOT_ `List<Integer>`.

Comment: @NirLevy The point that OP is using Array List.

Comment: @RomanC No he isn't. OP writes "Array List" in the title, but I wouldn't assume that he knows the difference.

Comment: @Tom When OP writes `numArray.get(i)` he misunderstood that `numArray` is not a `List`.

Comment: This is correct, so OP uses an array, not a List and the question is: why should he use a list here? It won't help him (and your code still won't compile). Directly accessing `numArray[i]` would be the much cleaner approach (like in the other answers).

Comment: @Tom There's no question why to use list, he was tried to use it and I gave him an answer, if he will try to use something else he will get another answer. There's no point to push the user an opinion that may be inappropriate or solve some quite another task.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `numArray[i]` instead of `numArray.get(i)`.